# Divio ImportError: cannot import name 's3boto'

Tags: divio

Recently I am getting the following error for my project. I changed nothing but suddenly this error appeared during deployment:

[0m[91m    from storages.backends import s3boto
[0m[91mImportError: cannot import name 's3boto'

Here is the complete output log:

```
[0m[91m    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[0m[91m    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
[0m[91m    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
[0m[91m    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[0m[91m    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[0m[91m  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[0m[91m  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[0m[91m  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[0m[91m  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[0m[91m  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[0m[91m  File "/app/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
[0m[91m    aldryn_addons.settings.load(locals())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aldryn_addons/settings.py", line 191, in load
[0m[91m    settings_json_path=settings_json_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aldryn_addons/settings.py", line 231, in load_addon_settings
[0m[91m    aldryn_config.Form().to_settings(addon_settings, settings),
  File "/app/addons/aldryn-django/aldryn_config.py", line 213, in to_settings
[0m[91m    self.storage_settings_for_media(settings, env=env)
  File "/app/addons/aldryn-django/aldryn_config.py", line 377, in storage_settings_for_media
[0m[91m    from aldryn_django.storage import parse_storage_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aldryn_django/storage.py", line 17, in <module>
[0m[91m    from storages.backends import s3boto
[0m[91mImportError: cannot import name 's3boto'
[0m
```

Answer (score 2):

The legacy S3BotoStorage backend was removed in version 1.9.
So, you will need either to pin django-storages in your project's requirements.in:

```
django-storages<1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by upgrading Aldryn Django version to 1.11.29.2